# Consumer Aware call on consumer thread safety

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am looking at the spring kafka document and one thing I am a bit confused is a sentence:

> The Consumer object is not thread-safe. You must only invoke its
>   methods on the thread that calls the listener.

The only way I would use this method on `Consumer` object is in the method which annotated with KafkaListener. Would it be thread safe if I call in that method? So anyone can explain more on that sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; it's safe there as long as you invoke it on the calling thread; this is **NOT** safe:

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "foo")
public void listen(String in, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
    ...
    executor.execute(() -> consumer.seek(...));
    ...
}
```